# Are there any full commanders in yellow shirts through ST:Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, starfleet-rank

Are there any characters who carry the rank of full commander who served in the yellow-shirt era for security, engineering, or tactical? Did these positions max out at Lieutenant Commander?

Comment: Just an out-of-universe reminder that command tunics in TOS only appeared yellow because a limitation in the TV cameras of the time rendered the green tunics yellow.

Answer (score 7):

You can go through this list of [Starfleet Commanders](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_commanders) and look for any in the Operations division, as they'll have gold uniforms (or the corresponding color for their time period or universe). The first one that immediately jumped out at me was Commander [Pete Harkins](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pete_Harkins), the officer in charge of the Pathfinder mission in Voyager.